# Want to call data from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, call

```php
    public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
    {

        $jobsInfo= Job::where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);
        return $jobsInfo->company_name;

    }
      public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
    {

        $jobsInfo= Job::where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);
        return $jobsInfo['company_name'];

    }
```

If i do that it shows --Undefined property also if i use return `$jobsInfo['company_name']` now it shows blank page I know there is `company_name` index also i tried another index also. Why is it doing that?

Comment: `$jobsInfo` return collections of data you need to use loop for this.

Comment: If i initialize company_name in a variable then i will use it another purpose is there any i can do that. I mean what i am trying to say that i want to show company_name data using a variable

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is not understanding what is returned by a paginate query. Have a good read of the docs for this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

That being said there are better ways of doing this with Laravel.

```
return Job::where('category_id', '=', $id)->select('company_name')->where('published', '=', 1)->get();
```

Will return a Collection of just `company_name` using the `select` function in the query builder.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects